# Where are the prices of secondary market TIPS trades?

Tags: united-states, bonds, government-bonds, tips

The primary market prices for Treasury Inflation-Protected Securities (TIPS) can be found on TreasuryDirect's [Auction Results](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/instit/annceresult/press/press_auctionresults.htm) webpage. But where can I find the prices for secondary market trades? Does the US Department of the Treasury publish secondary market price data for TIPS?

Comment: Googling "market price data for TIPS" gave [this WSJ page](https://www.wsj.com/market-data/bonds/tips), or do you want something else?

Comment: @TripeHound The Wall Street Journal is a third-party data source. Where is the primary source of TIPS secondary market trade data?

Comment: Presumably on secondary markets? For example, I can find them on my stock broker's website and view charts.

Comment: I suspect that the primary source of secondary market bond price data is FINRA's TRACE, which requires a paid subscription.

Answer (score 3):

The US Department of the Treasury does not publish secondary market price data for TIPS.  However, here are some other sources of secondary market price data for TIPS:

Treasury Direct:  You can view actual transactions (i.e., prices at which secondary market trades occurred) on the Treasury Direct website:  https://www.treasurydirect.gov/instit/auctfund/res/auctfund_ip_trans.htm
Bloomberg:  You can view secondary market prices for TIPS on the Bloomberg Terminal.

There are also other sources of secondary market price data for TIPS on the internet, but the two sources of price data that I listed above are the two most prominent.

Comment: I am getting "Page Not Found" for the TreasuryDirect link in your answer.